# Replace version in info.plist with bash script for Azure pipeline

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash script which replace info.plist version with one from pipeline variable.

For that, I started with simple script:

```
version="201.20108.2"
build="0"
input="info.plist"

isbundle=0
isbuild=0

linenum=0

bundlelinenum=0
buildlinenum=0

while IFS= read -r line;
do
    linenum=$((linenum+1))

    if [[ $line == *"CFBundleShortVersionString"* ]]; then
      isbundle=1
    elif [[ $line == *"CFBundleVersion"* ]]; then
      isbuild=1
    elif [[ $isbundle == 1 ]]; then
      bundlelinenum=$linenum
      isbundle=0
    elif [[ $isbuild == 1 ]]; then
      buildlinenum=$linenum
      isbuild=0
    fi
    
    echo $linenum
done < $input


sed -i '${bundlelinenum}s/.*/<string>$version/' $input
```

Since `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` are on separate line and then after them is coming version number, I want to update that line with version from $version and $buildnumber

the info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>17.2005.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>103</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and must be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>201.20108.2</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How to achieve that ?

Comment: Add a sample input and expected output to your question.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I posted update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bourne shell, variables inside single quotes are not substituted. Use double quotes:

```
sed -i "${bundlelinenum}s/.*/<string>$version/" "$input"
```

You probably want your closing `</string>` too:

```
sed -i "${bundlelinenum}s/>.*</>$version</" "$input"
```

Answer (score 0):

With a single GNU `sed` command, in one pass (without using line numbers):

```
version=201.20108.2
build=0
input=info.plist

sed -E '/<key>CFBundleShortVersionString<\/key>/{
           N
           s/(<string>).*(<\/string>)/\1'"$version"'\2/
       }
       /<key>CFBundleVersion<\/key>/{
           N
           s/(<string>).*(<\/string>)/\1'"$build"'\2/
       }' "$input"
```

Note that the variables `version` and `build` shouldn't contain characters that need to be quoted in `sed`.